# Moving fill background to the bottom after saving as jpg

Tags: matlab-figure

When I use fill or viscircles functions to plot circles with background to the plot, in figure it appears on the top of the plot, as it was intended, but after saving as jpg or png, the background moves to the bottom of the plot and is not visible anymore.

[image]

How do I fix this?

note: it's not because white is transparent color. I tried gray, I tried red, both are behaving the same as white.

Comment: Did you try [`export_fig`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig)? It's supposed to allow you to save figures closer to the way they are displayed.

Comment: @Dev-iL, I have tried it right now and it has the same problem.

Comment: Could you maybe upload the `.fig` file somewhere? I may be able to do something with it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider the following example (made on MATLAB 2015a):

```
figure(); h=cell(1);
%% viscircles method:
subplot(1,2,1);
plot([0 1],[0,1]); set(gca,'Color',0.8*[1 1 1]); axis square;
h{1} = viscircles([0.5,0.5], 0.1,'EdgeColor','k','DrawBackgroundCircle',false);
get(h{1},'Children')

%//  Line with properties:
%//
%//              Color: [0 0 0]
%//          LineStyle: '-'
%//          LineWidth: 2
%//             Marker: 'none'
%//         MarkerSize: 6
%//    MarkerFaceColor: 'none'
%//              XData: [1x182 double]
%//              YData: [1x182 double]
%//              ZData: [1x0 double]

%% Annotation method:
subplot(1,2,2);
plot([0 1],[0,1]); set(gca,'Color',0.8*[1 1 1]); axis square;
pos = get(gca,'position');
h{2} = annotation('ellipse',[pos(1)+pos(3)*0.5 pos(2)+pos(4)*0.5 0.1 0.1],...
                  'FaceColor','w')
%//  Ellipse with properties:
%//
%//        Color: [0 0 0]
%//    FaceColor: [1 1 1]
%//    LineStyle: '-'
%//    LineWidth: 0.5000
%//     Position: [0.7377 0.5175 0.1000 0.1000]
%//        Units: 'normalized'
```

When saving the output to `.jpg` I get the following result (which is identical to the preview within the figure):

[image: Comparison of two circle-drawing methods]

Notice the `FaceColor` property in the 2nd code cell, which is absent in the 1st object. The problem seems to be that the [`viscircles`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/viscircles.html) function you used is not supposed to draw a shape with a background, rather, it draws a line. It is unclear to me why you see the preview the way you do (i.e. with a background).

Sidenote: the `'DrawBackgroundCircle'` option for `viscircles` merely draws some white background for the outline.

You should try some alternate ways to plot filled circles, such as:

- Using `annotation` objects as in my example above. Note that these require you to provide coordinates in `figure` units (and not axes'!).
- Using [filled polygons](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html):

  ```
  N=20; c=[0.5,0.5]; r=0.1; color = [1 1 1];
  t = 2*pi/N*(1:N);
  hold all; fill(c(1)+r*cos(t), c(2)+r*sin(t), color);
  ```

  [ snippet is based on [a comment of this submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27703-draw-a-filled-circle) ]
- Plotting with giant markers:

  ```
  plot(0.5,0.5,'.r','MarkerSize',70);
  ```

  or

  ```
  scatter(0.5,0.5,70,'r','filled');
  ```

  [ snippet is based on [this answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/87111#answer_114641) ]. As mentioned in the link, the downside here is that marker size doesn't change with zoom.
- As a very last resort, you could save the image in some vectoric format (such as `.emf`), edit it (with something like [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/)), bring the background circles to a higher layer and export it.

Comment: Indeed your code produces circles with white background even after saving to jpg. But I plot multiple plots in one figure and I need the circles to be precisely at certain position. I don't know how to get precise position of specific plot. I don't know how large spaces are between plots. Moreover I'm using panel function to reduce those spaces.

Comment: Mapping axis coordinates from and to figure coordinates can be done as explained in [this MATLAB Central answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/61816).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
print('-painters','-dpng','myFile')
```

or

```
print('-painters','-dsvg','myFile')
```

Logic: from [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html#input_argument_renderer) appears that the model of rendering is changed from painter (what you intended) to OpenGL when saving the file. I suspect that OpenGL does not respect you intentions and forcing the renderer to *painter* will solve the problem. But it is not clear if 
*painter* rendering can be used for bitmap images and not only vector images, so first example can fail.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, but this approach makes no difference. Still doesn't work.